# Selenium web driver code in python for clicking an image

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I need a help in python code so that I can have click event on image as `Sony` using `selenium` `webdriver`. 
I am new to selenium web driver & python. 
Please note that after clicking on "Testing Inc." image, next page is having login details will be displayed.

Here is the Javascript code:-

```
<div class="idpDescription float"><span class="largeTextNoWrap indentNonCollapsible">Sony Inc.</span></div> <span class="largeTextNoWrap indentNonCollapsible">Sony Inc.</span>
```

Python code written by me but click event is not happening on clicking the image:-

```
import os 
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# get the path of IEDriverServer 
dir = os.path.dirname(file) 
Ie_driver_path = dir + "\IEDriverServer.exe"
#create a new IE session 
driver = webdriver.Ie("D:\SCripts\IEDriverServer.exe") 
driver.maximize_window()
#navigate to the application home page 
driver.get("example.com") 
element=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Testing Inc.").click();
```

Comment: share the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared and your code trial as you are trying to invoke `click()` on the *WebElement* with text as **Sony Inc.** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the element to be clickable as follows :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# other lines of code
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='idpDescription float']/span[@class='largeTextNoWrap indentNonCollapsible']"))).click()
```

You can get more granular adding the *Link Text* to the *xpath* as follows :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# other lines of code
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='idpDescription float']/span[@class='largeTextNoWrap indentNonCollapsible' and contains(.,'Sony Inc.')]"))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Debanjan, you solved my problem. Thanks for sharing detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

When you search using `by_partial_link_text`, Selenium expects text inside an `a` html tag. Since it is inside a `span`, it will not find it.

What you can do:

1. Write a Css selector to find the tag that contains the desired image using only tags and attributes. Here you need to check the whole HTML. Since I don't have access to that, I can only assume the below example.

   ```
   div.idpDescription span
   ```
2. Write an XPath based on the text content. XPath may be more difficult for you to understand since you are not used to developing with Selenium.

   ```
   //span[text()='Sony Inc.']
   ```